# primeng: p-menu without styling

Tags: angular, primeng

I installed angular 16.2.10 and then primeng 16.9.1
My package.json is:

```js
{
  "name": "tester",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^16.9.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.10",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Then I created a simple menu with the following code:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-buttons',
  templateUrl: './menu-buttons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-buttons.component.scss']
})
export class MenuButtonsComponent {
  public menuItems: MenuItem[];

  constructor() {
    this.menuItems = [
      {
        label: 'File',
        items: [
          {label: 'Save'},
          {separator: true},
          {label: 'Open Workspace'},
          {label: 'Save Workspace'}
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

```css
:host {

    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <p-menubar [model]="menuItems" [styleClass]="'menu-buttons'"></p-menubar>
</div>
```

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Tester": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/tester",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Tester:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "Tester:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Tester:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the following menu:

[image]

Can you please tell what is the reason I'm not getting the default style of p-menu.
It should be something like (without icons):

[image]

How should I set the default styling of p-menubar ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you add primeng styles in your style file or angular json? Reference: https://primeng.org/installation#styles

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I added it to angular.json but with no change. I pasted my new angular.json in my question.

Comment: If you updated your style.css and angular.json how to mentioned @Schrader,  and you added  import { MenubarModule } from 'primeng/menubar';  in app.module.ts , should be work here example with your configuration: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sqqqzh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Henry - Thank you very much ! It's working.